# jQuery on keypress console log input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, keypress

Having a weird minor little issue with submitting an input field on a keypress event - specifically enter.

Following is my js code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#findMyCouncillor').on('keypress', function (event) {
      var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
      if(keycode == '13') {
        var search = $(this).val();
        console.log(search);
      }
    });
  });
```

And relevant html:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input id="findMyCouncillor" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search....">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that console.log(search); is working - but search is empty. console.log(typeof search) returns string - but it looks empty? It just console logs a blank line...is this expected?

Perhaps the above code is the wrong way entirely, essentially on enter I want to grab whatever value has been input into the search field...

Comment: This works as expected for me https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aqygJj

Comment: I don't get the issue. I pasted your code into a JS Fiddle and it works as expected...

Comment: Thank you. It must be somthing else on the page...